# Align text under left side of image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align both paragraphs under the left side of an image, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am also trying to make the width of the text the same width of the image. I need to keep the div align="center" in there so the bootstrap row is on the center of the page. Please help!

Here is an image from my web design on how i'm trying to align it. [http://i.imgur.com/kIbyBUS.png](https://i.imgur.com/kIbyBUS.png)

Here is the html code.
https://jsfiddle.net/kvu7y8ym/

```html
    <div align="center">
      <div id="preview" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img id="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/HHGHTsu.png">
        <p><b>EXAMPLE WEB DESIGN</b></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Vestibulum lobortis diam ut ipsum egestas scelerisque. Nam semper lorem 
    at cursus pulvinar. Ut luct diam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp according to this page, the "align" attribute is not supported in html 5, which means there has to be another way to do it with CSS... I think you should  be centering your bootstrap row with something like "margin:auto" and a defined width

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mp9o0qcc/2/
something more like this, though this solution requires a fixed pixel width, to force the div to have the same width as the image. Unless there is some other reason I don't understand why you absolutely need that align="center", using tags for positioning is sketchy.

Comment: @slackOverflow im not using html5, i must have accidentally clicked the wrong one when adding a tag to the post. Im using standard html so the align attribute does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest to accomplish that is to use 2 wrappers, an `inline-block` and a `table-caption`.

The `table-caption` will keep the text within the image's edges, and the `inline-block` will be centered with the `text-align: center` set on the `#preview` element.

```css
#preview {
  text-align: center;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tbl-caption {
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="preview" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="inline-block">
      <div class="tbl-caption">
        <img id="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/HHGHTsu.png">
        <p><b>EXAMPLE WEB DESIGN</b></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lobortis diam ut ipsum egestas scelerisque. Nam semper lorem at cursus pulvinar. Ut luct diam.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div id="preview" class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img id="img" src="http://i.imgur.com/HHGHTsu.png">
        <p><b>EXAMPLE WEB DESIGN</b></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Vestibulum lobortis diam ut ipsum egestas scelerisque. Nam semper lorem 
    at cursus pulvinar. Ut luct diam.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd do it this way if you're using Bootstrap (which it seems like you are because you're using `col-lg-4` etc.

When you use those classes they expect to be inside `container` and then inside a `row` use different offsets to center the content after that, see example above.